# Comparing 2 array with different value positions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two unknown arrays, and I want to know if they are equal, no matter the position of their elements, ex:

```
A = [1,3,7]
B = [3,7,1]
-> return true

A = [1,3]
B = [1,3,7]
-> return false

A = [1,3,7]
B = [1,4]
-> return false
```

Should I sort it first, and then compare? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
function checkTwoArray(arr, brr) {
    var a = arr.sort();
    var b= brr.sort();
    var i = a.length;
    if (i != b.length) return false;
    while (i--) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: This will return false for the first case, where the OP expects true. The position of the elements should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
var areEqual = $(A).not(B).length == 0 && $(B).not(A).length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 solutions, one better than the other.

one is, as you suggested, to sort the array(s) first and then compare them. (i would suggest this one as well)

the second way is to iterate through one array, comparing to each element in the second array, and saving (and skipping) the indices at which the values were found.
the last solution however, is somewhat slow and too complicated

code example of the second:

```
function compare(a, b)
{
    if(a.length != b.length) { return false; }
    var c = [];
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        var f = false;//current value found in second array
        for(j=0;j<b.length;b++)
        {
            if(j in c) { continue; }//array c contains value j, so at this index, a value from 'a' is found in 'b' (maybe some other code should be used here, like indexOf() or jQuery.inArray())
            if(a[i] == b[j]) { c.push(j); f = true; }
        }
        if(!f)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

i am not entirely sure this code will actually work (i have not tested it).

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and stringify and compare to check whether the arrays are equal:

i.e. `A.sort().join(',') === B.sort().join(',')`

---

```
var A = [1,3,7];
var B = [3,7,1];
console.log("Equal: " + (A.sort().join(',') === B.sort().join(','));
```

Comment: I think you want a delimiter.  Otherwise, [1,1]==[11].

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareArray(a, b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
          if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's usually preferable to have some non-code explanation to go along with what you've written.  But in this case, there are three other answers that also go along the lines of "sort it first, and then compare", so I don't know that you've added anything to the question.  (And do you need a custom sort function?)

Comment: how about the order of checks for array length and then sorting and comparing. ofcourse custom sort function is not required